# Undefined method 'views' after installing devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting this error:

`method_missing': undefined method`views' for #

when trying to run '->rails generate devise user'

I also just tried to do '->rails s' to start the server but it is not working and is showing the same error. I am completely new to RoR and might have messed something up when following this tutorial...

Please Help!

EDIT: FULL ERROR:

```
                                            /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing': undefined method `views' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x007fd0a1b02880> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/myname/Desktop/rails-projects/First_App/config/application.rb:61:in `<class:Application>'
from /Users/myname/Desktop/rails-projects/First_App/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:FirstApp>'
from /Users/myname/Desktop/rails-projects/First_App/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Does it tell you where the method originates from?  What file is it in?

Comment: .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb

Comment: can you show which tutorial you followed? and the full error.

Comment: I am following this tutorial: http://teamtreehouse.com/library/programming/build-a-simple-ruby-on-rails-application/creating-an-authentication-system/installing-devise

Comment: You should also post your code so we can see how you're implementing everything.